# Is there a legit way to zoom out more?

Tags: starcraft-2

Any legit way to zoom out more in Starcraft 2?
I feel like I could handle much more information on the screen.
If I could zoom out a little further, it'd be awesome.

Comment: I felt this way too after switching from another game, that the camera was zoomed in WAY too much. But you get used to the field of view.

Comment: after playing Supreme Commander any RTS that doesn't zoom out all the way feels too limited.

Comment: I added pictures to my answer to better display the actual difference in aspect ratios.

Comment: Actually, while the game was in beta, there was a patch you could apply which would allow you to zoom way out. It didn't seem to slow the game down at all. The patch worked fine until the game went live. As such, I think that not allowing you to zoom way out is rather silly. The justifications that people have given for not allowing it are rather poor.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is no legal way to zoom out more. However, if you are not currently playing on a widescreen monitor, and if you can acquire one, picking a widescreen resolution will display a small bit more.

After a bit of poking around, [I found some comparison shots on the Team Liquid forums](http://www.teamliquid.net/forum/viewpost.php?post_id=4726427) displaying the differences between the three aspect ratios. Each of the pictures below is centered on the Command Center (and I'm not sure why it's German, but it is).

**16x9**

[image]

**16x10**

[image]

**4x3**

[image]

Comment: What about ATI Eyefinity? That gives you Extra-wide resolutions, will it increase the area displayed?

Comment: @Bruce -- As far as I know, Starcraft 2 does not support extra-wide resolution: the extra space will either not be used (as if the game were letterboxed) or the widescreen view will be stretched to fill the space.

Comment: @Bruce -- I suppose I should clarify that I do not know anything, specifically, about Eyefinity. Starcraft 2 supports 4:3, 16:9 and 16:10. If any of those are considered "Eyefinity Extra-wide", I don't know.

Comment: Yeah, that's probably more suited as a separate question. I asked because eyefinity actually manages to increase the resolution even in games that don't originally support it, but that's a case by case thing.

Comment: @Bruce I just tried it and curiously ended up with two complete images of the game on each monitor.

Answer (score 10):

This isn't possible. If the game were designed so that you could zoom out as far as you wanted, the optimal view would be to see the whole map at once. Then you'd end up with competitive advantages for the player with a powerful enough machine to render it all, or players reducing the graphics setting to the point where all the painstakingly-modeled units are mere dots and blobs. The lower limit of zoom level had to be set to *something*.

Learn to keep a third eye on the minimap! (Then tell me how, because I sure can't.)

Custom maps can lift this restriction and allow whatever camera positions they want, of course.

Comment: +1 for "Learn to keep a third eye on the minimap! (Then tell me how, because I sure can't.)"

Comment: It is important to note that SC2 doesn't reduce the detail if the game is more zoomed out on custom maps, so it will increase the load on your PC the more you zoom out, unlike supreme commander where the details are reduced (up to being just small icons).

Comment: If you get a wide-screen monitor it still gives you an advantage. The wider it is, the more advantage you get, as only the vertical view spread seems to be enforced by SC2.

Comment: This isn't the case- the developers can reduce the LoD. This system is already implemented in Supreme Commander and Supreme Commander 2, and works very well. Those games have plenty of other flaws; but their zoom functionality isn't it.