# Warcraft 3 : Zoom out

Tags: macos, warcraft-3-the-frozen-throne

I have a 27" Cinema Display with Mac OS X 10.6.5 .

So I would really like to play Frozen Throne one my big screen but everything is soo big, it's really annoying :(

Is there any way to zoom out? Any hacks or some tools or tips, something?

Comment: Given that it's a game in the same genre produced by the same company, this question / answer might also account for this question: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/12375/any-legit-way-to-zoom-out-more-in-starcraft-2

Answer (score 3):

Do the following:

1. Open `System Preferences` **>** `Displays` and get your screen's resolution.
2. Open *Warcraft III* and go to `Options` **>** `Video and` set the resolution to the same.
3. Play the game fullscreen and enjoy.

If you want to effect camera zoom, you can use the vertical scrollwheel of the mouse or I think the <kbd>+</kbd> and <kbd>-</kbd> keys to zoom in and out.

Comment: I'm on warcraft 3 reforged on macos. Scroll wheel changes the angle, doesn't really zoom in . pressing plus and minus does nothing

Answer (score 0):

you can set your maps to be able to zoom in or zoom out. follow this tutorial:

Answer (score -1):

A little bit of searching around seems to indicate that this might be possible with War3. Try [this](http://antjedi.homeip.net/wordpress/?p=19) out, I have tried this on Windows (Registry Editing and all that) but this is with Mac

Comment: I think it is usually best to cite the pertinent information, or a summary thereof, in your answer.  Yes, I know this is an old answer, and you probably forgot about it.

Answer (score -1):

Try this command after the game start (in game chat):

```
-cam 1.40
```

where `1.00` is normal(100%) distance and `1.40` in example is 40% zoomed out of normal distance.

---

*I just tried this command in custom map `Dota LOD Map 6.83` and it was working as expected. I'm not sure about other `warcraft III` maps.*

---

UPDATE:

On DOTA maps I found a book icon around buttons where you can buyback your hero when he/she dies (your hero reserved location near foundation). If you click on the book you'll see buttons to `zoom in` and `zoom out` plus other settings for `mouse right click deny` support and `auto attack` and ...

Comment: Custom maps implement zoom commands at their discretion, and there is no standard syntax. Only a small subset of maps bother to implement one.